# Best way to feed a label in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, label, training-data

I have a training set composed by images, from witch I have to predict a label that is formed by a fixed number of letters and numbers.
What is the best way to feed these labels into tensorflow?. I thought to create a list of numbers, one for all the chars/numbers in the label.
I created a list with alla the possible values:

```
__dict = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
          'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

then I use the index of the letter in the `__dict` variable to encode the label into a list of numbers.
For example:

```
label = abc
label_encoded = [0, 1, 2]
```

Is it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a unique integer for each of your labels, i.e aaa=0, aab=1, etc

It is convenient for you to use a positional encoding with base 36 (if letters are lowercase english characters + numbers).

I don't know the problem you are facing, but pay attention to the fact that this could lead to a huge number of labels (i.e. output classes for your classification problem)

Comment: In this way I have to create all the possible labels. It can be very expensive.  Is there a way similar to what I initially thought? Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the problem: if the label "aaa" and "bcd" do not share anything, then they should be treated as different classes of your classification problem, and yes, you have to create every possible label. Everything depends mostly on what you want to achieve.